# How to find AWS RDS Postgresql storage space utilized or consumed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using AWS RDS Postgresql. We have allocated 100GB of space. We also see 100 GB free storage space from RDS Monitoring.

We like to know, how much RDS postgresql storage space is utilized or consumed?

Below URL did not help much
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html

I ran the below sql query but data_length and data_free column are not there in table

SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name",
SUM( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 /
1024 "Data Base Size in MB",
SUM( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema ;

How to find the Storage space consumed for AWS RDS Postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. I used PGADMIN and connected to the database. Under database statistics, you can find the size of the database

Answer (score 1):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/diskfull-error-rds-postgresql/ offers instructions on using Cloudwatch to find free space